# Heat Generation in Watts per cubic meter - how to apply this to a volume?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, volume, convection

Water is running through a pipe. The pipe is heated uniformly in order to heat the water running through the pipe. I want to calculate how much heat needs to be generated by the pipe in order to heat the water by a certain amount, e.g. from 10C to 30C.
I found a formula for this here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7D8n-lLIV24

The formula is -

Heat generation in Watts per cubic meter = Heat Transfer rate in Watts divided by Volume in Cubic meters

The **Heat Transfer rate** is calculated as

Heat Transfer rate=m*cp*(T out - T in)

Where

m= flow rate in kg/s

cp=heat capacity of water in joules/kg*Kelvin

T out = desired temperature in C

T in = starting temperature in C

The **Volume** is calculated as

Volume = (pi/4)*(Outer Diameter^2 - Inner Diameter^2)*Length of pipe
All in meters

My question is this - if the answer is given in Watts per cubic meter, which equals Joules per second per cubic meter, how do I apply this figure to a pipe that has less than 1 cubic meter per second flowing through it?

For example, if the Heat Generation is 20 Watts per cubic meter, but the pipe has 0.1 cubic meters flowing per second - do I apply this to the figure of 20 Watts per cubic meter, giving me 2 Watts? At first I thought this was not necessary, and the formula already accounts for the water volume, but I now am thinking that the Volume in the formula is for the pipe, and not for the water inside the pipe. I am confused about how to read the results of the formula.

For anyone interested, the formula for my confusion is

I never had a chance to study Physics at all = the internet is how I educate myself = I may be making a very basic error!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the heat is being generated uniformly within the water, then you use the 2 watts.